# how to add the count of followers in the data set(most active user)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

i have a dataset of a social network contaning information about how follows how
i need to find most active user(for example the user that dose most followings)
my data set lines are like bellow

```
 1000066:262792,273106,590979,1152305,1691577,1888250
```

and some of them are like these

```
1000073:private
1000069:notfound
```

questions 1: how to make rdd of any line in the way the key of all rdd pairs would be the first number that separated with ':' and values one by one separated with ','? 
question 2:
how could i solve this problem using graphx?
All i need is to find most active user in this dataset
thanks in advance, answering any off these too will help

Answer (score 1):

Q1. You could create a RDD tuple of `(user, followers)`

In a map function pass each line of the RDD to:

```
def createTuple(s: String) = {
  val kv = s.split(":")
  val user = kv(0)
  val followers = kv(1).split(",")
  val count = followers.length

  (user, followers, count)
}
```

Comment: this followers is an array of string in this case we must have an Rdd like this [String, Array(String)] it could be useful but how to find the count of each followers whit this RDD?

Comment: this followers is an array of string in this case we must have an Rdd like this [String, Array(String)] it could be useful but how to find the count of each followers whit this RDD?

Comment: edited the question to add the count. could be done in many other ways..